# How do I reclaim 36 GB of missing space on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, storage

I have a 64GB iPhone 5S with iOS 8.4, but I'm only able to access 28 GB of space.

iTunes reports a capacity of 55.92GB, but in the usage graph at the bottom of the summary page, I see:

- 13.61 GB Free
- 1.58 GB Other
- 1.09 GB Documents & Data
- 5.13 GB Apps
- 248.3 MB Photos
- 6.34 GB Audio

The Setting->Usage->Storage app says:

- Used: 42.9 GB
- Available 13.0 GB

I've tried rebooting and updating the OS from 8.3 to 8.4.

I'm hoping to avoid a solution that involves wiping the phone and resetting it. Is there anything else I can do to reclaim my missing 36 GB of space?

Comment: On the phone go to Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage and see what you learn there.

Comment: I did; the result is in the original question. Besides listing my apps and the amount of space taken by each it says I'm using 42.9 GB and and have available 13 GB. The usage summary adds up basically to what iTunes reports.

Comment: Don't just look at the totals from the phone tho, the detail shown there is much more accurate than iTunes.

Comment: Adding up the total space used by the apps from that list is similar to what iTunes reports for used space. It does not account for the missing storage.

Answer (score 1):

You said you don't want to wipe the phone and reset it, but what about restoring it from a backup? During an iCloud restore, iOS re-downloads most of what it needs from Apple’s servers, so the process might reclaim your lost space, since iOS wouldn’t assign it to anything that isn't actually using it. After the restore, your phone would be returned to the same state you left it in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of restoring from a backup, one might want to try *logging out of iCloud and back in again*.  For me, that fixed a lot of unexplained occupied space.

Furthermore, if you're looking for a possible explanation in your case, in [a different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162825/iphone-available-space-significant-difference-between-itunes-and-iphone) it was suggested that iTunes Match could be the reason.  (I don't use it myself.)