# Why do iTunes and iPhone not show the same space used?

Tags: iphone, itunes, storage

Unlike this previous [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/162825/4642), it's not related to iTunes Match (haven't ever had it on).

[[image: iPhone]][3]
[image: iTunes]

Why is there such a discrepancy?

Comment: I was the one that asked that previous question. iTunes match not on on the said iPhone, either. I suspect it is related to cached files (Streaming video, music...), but not able to find a solution or workaround yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had significantly *more* free memory displayed on the iPhone, while iTunes considered the phone to be full.

**Logging out of iCloud and back in again on the phone** helped. It is some hassle (at least, I had to reconfigure iCloud and there was some waiting time), but less than the complete reset & restore from backup suggested by others.