# iPhone Storage Space Inaccuracy (No Storage Space)

Tags: iphone, storage

I have an 8GB iPhone 4s and it always says I have no space. However when I go into `Settings > General > Usage` It says that I have `1.3GB` of free space. I only have 5 photos and 3 Apps downloaded on my iPhone. Why does it constantly say I have no space when it should?

Comment: Depending on the apps they can gobble space pretty bad. How much space are the apps using?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I have seen a lot of space taken up with the "other" category in the graph of space taken up on your iPhone in iTunes. Fixing that is not actually that difficult.

1. Back up your iPhone to your computer (I would encrypt the backup as the backup will then save all your passwords too, which it does not do if you don't encrypt the backup.)
2. Once done go into Settings > general > reset and erase all settings and data. (you may have to first turn off Find My iPhone, if its on, under iCloud)
3. When the phone reboots, plug it back into the computer, launch iTunes and restore the phone from the backup you just made.

Usually when you do this, if there is a lot of temporary or unneeded data on the phone this will do some house cleaning and free up some space. No guarantee this is your issue but it is easy enough to do and you won't lose anything except maybe an hour (or less) of your time.

Comment: A less invasive way could be [logging out of iCloud and back in again](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/325212/49438)

Answer (score 0):

you can see what is eating up storage space: In your `Settings` app, go to `General > Usage > Manage Storage`.
Your phone will compute the space used by each application and their respective data.

Note: Hope I'm right with the menu names as my phone is in french...  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem where the storage would not add up, after so much researching, I found out that Telegram app caches all the datas but does not show it in the `Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage`. If you are using Telegram App, go to it's `Settings > Data and Storage > Storage Usage` and there you can Clear Cache and free up some space.